# R cannot download websockets package from the github

Tags: r, websocket, devtools

The manual is written here:https://github.com/Refinitiv/websocket-api/tree/master/Applications/Examples/R

The mentioned code is written in Section 2 of Install libraries
Problems are with this part

```
library(devtools)
install_github("brettjbush/R-Websockets")
```

With R and RTools versions above 4.0 I have following error.

```
> install_github("brettjbush/R-Websockets")
Downloading GitHub repo brettjbush/R-Websockets@HEAD
Installing 1 packages: caTools
Installing package into ‘\\energia.sise/dfs/REDIRECT/german.suhharukov/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/caTools_1.18.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 317292 bytes (309 KB)
downloaded 309 KB

package ‘caTools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\german.suhharukov\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoRYGc0\downloaded_packages
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\german.suhharukov\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoRYGc0\remotes1aa03e212c08\brettjbush-R-Websockets-fc7ee9c/DESCRIPTION' (1s)
-  preparing 'websockets':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
   Warning in system2(command, args, stdout = NULL, stderr = NULL, ...) :
     'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\rtools40\usr\bin\make.exe -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/share/make/clean.mk" -f Makevars.win clean'
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'websockets_1.1.7.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘\\sise/dfs/REDIRECT/MYNAME/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
'\\sise\dfs\REDIRECT\MYNAME\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'websockets' ...
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
Error in system(cmd) : 
  (converted from warning) 'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\rtools40\usr\bin\make.exe -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="websockets.dll" OBJECTS="libsock.o"'
* removing '\\sise/dfs/REDIRECT/MYNAME/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/websockets'
Error: Failed to install 'websockets' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/MYNAME/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoRYGc0/file1aa0518554ea/websockets_1.1.7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
> install.packages("caTools")
Installing package into ‘\\sise/dfs/REDIRECT/MYNAME/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/caTools_1.18.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 317292 bytes (309 KB)
downloaded 309 KB

package ‘caTools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\XXXXXXX\downloaded_packages
>
```

Errors are following

```
> library(devtools)
Loading required package: usethis
> install_github("brettjbush/R-Websockets")
Downloading GitHub repo brettjbush/R-Websockets@master
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe'
Content type 'application/x-msdownload' length 108622512 bytes (103.6 MB)
downloaded 103.6 MB

Error: Failed to install 'websockets' from GitHub:
  Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
Call `pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` to diagnose the problem.
> pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe'
Content type 'application/x-msdownload' length 108622512 bytes (103.6 MB)
downloaded 103.6 MB

Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
Call `pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` to diagnose the problem.

> find_rtools()
[1] TRUE
> Sys.which("ls.exe")
                   ls.exe 
"C:\\Rtools\\bin\\ls.exe"
```

How can I download this package?

Answer (score 0):

In the notes on github it says "NOTE: This package is no longer maintained. For implementing websocket servers in R, try the httpuv package"

Another possible problem could be that you are running a new version of R with an old version of Rtools. So I'd try to install the newest version of Rtools or run an older version of R with a compatible version of Rtools, such that you can build and compile the package.

I ran your code on my machine running R 4.0.2 and Rtools 4.0.0 and did not face any issues installing the package. So I'd suggest installinng the newest version of R and Rtools from here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and trying again.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I updated everything, and still, errors persist. Could you send the output from the following code, which includes rtools40 in your paths:1( Sys.getenv('PATH') and 2)Sys.which("make")

Comment: Yes, the output for 1) includes "C:\\Rtools\\bin" and the output for 2) is > Sys.which("make")
                       make 
"C:\\Rtools\\bin\\make.exe"